# Comparing adjacent time stamps

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, datetime, csv

I have this code which compares two adjacent time stamps. If they are less than 15 min apart, it adds a new time stamp (row) in between with the new time stamp equal to the previous time + 15 min and value equal to the previous time stamp. If there is more than one-time stamp missing (more than 15 min interval), it adds a number of time stamps with + 15 min interval each. Sample value equal to last recorded value.

CSV file looks something like this:

> ```
> "Time stamp","Value","Events","Comment","User"
> "5/07/2016 7:07:54 PM","7.00","","",""
> "5/07/2016 6:37:52 PM","14.00","","",""
> "5/07/2016 6:22:51 PM","26.00","","",""
> "5/07/2016 6:07:50 PM","9.00","","",""
> "5/07/2016 7:22:06 AM","0.00","","",""
> "5/07/2016 7:07:05 AM","16.00","","",""
> "5/07/2016 6:52:04 AM","25.00","","",""
> ```

At the moment it is doing what it suppose to do but in wrong direction, because the .csv file was created from bottom up.

```
for (var currentRow = 0; currentRow < dgvValues.Rows.Count; currentRow++)
    {
        for (var cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < dgvValues.Rows[currentRow].Cells.Count; cellIndex++)
        {
            if (cellIndex > 0 && cellIndex < dgvValues.Rows[currentRow].Cells.Count)
            {
                buffer += ",";
            }
            buffer += dgvValues.Rows[currentRow].Cells[cellIndex].Value.ToString();
        }
        buffer += "\n";

        pleasewait.LabelText = (currentRow.ToString() + " of " + numRows + " rows processed");
        Application.DoEvents();

        if (currentRow + 1 >= dgvValues.Rows.Count) continue;
        {
            var firstDate = Parse(dgvValues.Rows[currentRow].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            var secondDate = Parse(dgvValues.Rows[currentRow + 1].Cells[0].Value.ToString());

            var timespan = firstDate - secondDate;
            double min = -15;
            firstDate = firstDate.AddMinutes(min);

            if (timespan.TotalMinutes > 15)
            {
                if (firstDate == secondDate)
                    @equals = true;
                while (timespan.TotalMinutes > 15 && !@equals)
                {
                    timespan = firstDate - secondDate;
                    for (var cellIndex = 0;
                        cellIndex < dgvValues.Rows[currentRow].Cells.Count;
                        cellIndex++)
                    {
                        if (cellIndex > 0 && cellIndex < dgvValues.Rows[currentRow].Cells.Count)
                        {
                            buffer += ",";
                        }
                        if (cellIndex != 0)
                        {
                            buffer += dgvValues.Rows[currentRow].Cells[cellIndex].Value.ToString();
                        }
                        else
                            buffer += Parse(firstDate.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
                    }
                    buffer += "\n";
                    min = -15;
                    firstDate = firstDate.AddMinutes(min);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you think the offset to the rigtht is something anyone would want to deal with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is way too "linear", too deep, too hard to follow with all the indexing and generic column-cell referencing.

- I prefer `foreach` over `for`.  Simpler, cleaner, easier to read.
- For each row, you can reference the `DataGridViewCellCollection` property by column name-value: `theRow.Cells['theColumnName'].Value`
- Create a method that takes a `DataGridViewRow` parameter and simply copies its column values into a "CSVrow" object - a class you create.

  - override `ToString` and build the CSV string there.
- Create a "CSVrowCollection" class to hold the CSV objects.

  - Its main purpose is to build the CSV file. Do this in a `ToString` override

.

```
class CSV {
    public CSV (DataGridViewRow timeStampRow) {  }

    public override string ToString() {
        // note the single quote characters wrapping the complete string
        return string.Format('"{0}","{1}","{2}","{3}","{4}","{5}"', 
                            Timestamp, Value, Events, Comment, User);
    }
}

class CSVcollection {
    protected List<CSV> CsvList { get; set; }

    public void Add(CSV aCsvObject) { }

    public override string ToString() {
        // building the value names string not shown.
        StringBuilder me = new StringBuilder();  //System.Text

        foreach (var record in CsvList)
           me.AppendLine(record);  //implicit ToString call

        return me.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.
Follow up question: How Do I replace values more than 1000 with 0 without disturbing the date "2016"

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean the potential for a year roll-over as new "+15 minute dateTimes" are created?

Comment: Re: "how do I replace ...".  This could be done in the `CSV` constructor: `this.Value = timeStampRow.Cells['Value'].Value >= 1000 ? 0 : timeStampRow.Cells['Value'].Value`

Answer (score 1):

`@equals` is really a bad name for variable. Also, if you are not using `@equals` else where you don't even need `if` condition.

**Before**

```
if (firstDate == secondDate)
    @equals = true;
while (timespan.TotalMinutes > 15 && !@equals)
{
    ...
}
```

**After**

```
while (timespan.TotalMinutes > 15 && firstDate != secondDate)
{
    ...
}
```

---

Use `Foreach` for cleaner code and `RowType` to check for header this will save you all kind of extra validations

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in dgvValues.Rows)
{
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        continue;

    ...
}
```

---

Make use of `string.Format` for more readability

**Before**

```
pleasewait.LabelText = (currentRow.ToString() + " of " + numRows + " rows processed");
```

**After**

```
pleasewait.LabelText = $"{currentRow.ToString()} of {numRows} rows processed"; // C# 6.0 

pleasewait.LabelText = string.Format("{0} of {1} rows processed", currentRow.ToString(), numRows); // Previous version of C#
```

---

You don't need braces here. This will saves you from nesting.

```
if (currentRow + 1 >= dgvValues.Rows.Count) continue;
{
   ...
}
```

---

Some other observations:

- Use `Environment.NewLine` whenever possible.
- You can do negative checks first and return. This will results in much readable and less number of lines in code.
- If you are doing much string concatenation use `StringBuilder` class. This will give you huge performance.
- You don't need `this` to access variables
- There are lot of unnecessary conditional checks which can be avoided

---

After implementing above suggestions, your code will be similar to below:

```
var buffer = new StringBuilder();

foreach (GridViewRow row in dgvValues.Rows)
{
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        continue;

    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        buffer.Append(",");
        buffer.Append(cell.Value);
    }

    buffer.Append(Environment.NewLine);

    pleasewait.LabelText = $"{currentRow.ToString()} of {numRows} rows processed";

    ...

    if (firstDate == secondDate)
        continue;

    var timespan = firstDate - secondDate;

    while (timespan.TotalMinutes > 15)
    {
       ...
    }

}
```